# how can i send the multiple images with same keyword in postman that send as multi dimensional array

Tags: arrays, express, postman, multer

Using node express API I need to send multiple files as a multi-dimensional array.

```
uploads(req, res, async (err) => {
      if (!req.files || req.files == "") {
        const updated_response = setErrorResponseMsg(
          RESPONSE.PARAMETER_IS_MANDATORY,
          "Image"
        );
        return send(res, updated_response);
      } else if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        return send(res, RESPONSE.FILE_SIZE);
      }
      if (err) {
        return send(res, RESPONSE.UNKNOWN_ERROR);
      }
      let filenames = [];
      if (req.files != null) {
        req.files.forEach((ele) => {
          filenames.push(ele.filename);
        });
      }
      console.log(filenames);
    });
```

[image]

getting o/p like this

```
[
  '1698209701924.png',
  '1698209701924.png',
  '1698209701925.png',
  '1698209701927.png',
  '1698209701933.png'
]
```

need o/p like this (multi-dimensional array) instead of above

```
[['1698209701924.png',
  '1698209701924.png',
  '1698209701925.png'],
 ['1698209701927.png',
  '1698209701933.png']]
```